# Unable to connect to SASL Kafka broker using kaf

Tags: apache-kafka

I am following this article https://gitlab.com/ShowMeYourCodeYouTube/kafka-producer-consumer/-/tree/master/

My `docker-compose` file is https://gitlab.com/ShowMeYourCodeYouTube/kafka-producer-consumer/-/blob/master/docker-compose-ssl.yml

`SERVER_JAAS.conf` used for `auth login` is like below

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="kafkabroker"
   password="kafkabroker-secret"
   user_kafkabroker="kafkabroker-secret"
   user_client="client-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="kafka"
   password="kafka-secret";
};
```

My `docker-compose ps` looks like below

```
NAME                IMAGE                             COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
kafka1-ssl          confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   kafka1-ssl          38 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       0.0.0.0:9093-9094->9093-9094/tcp, 9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:29093-29094->29093-29094/tcp
zookeeper-ssl       confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   zookeeper1          39 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

My `kaf cli` config reads below

```
- name: ssl_local
  version: ""
  brokers:
  - localhost:29094
  SASL:
    mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
    username: "kafkabroker"
    password: "kafkabroker-secret"
    clientID: ""
    clientSecret: ""
    tokenURL: ""
    token: ""
  TLS: null
  security-protocol: SASL_SSL
  schema-registry-url: ""
```

Now when i am trying to connect to broker and list the topics, I am getting below error

```
>> kaf topic ls
Unable to get cluster admin: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match localhost
```

Comment: What happens when you try localhost:9093 since that's the host advertised address?

Comment: any updates? I got same issue